# ListContourPlot: Not all labels are shown

Tags: plotting

I am trying to create a contour plot for the data I have, and I want to show all the labels on the plot but I am getting only 3 labels using `ContourLabels`, how can I show them all?

```
ListContourPlot[{{21.87, 6.76, 0.045}, {13.86, 4.79, 0.053}, {13.22, 3.8, 0.063}, {11.41, 4.62, 0.064}, {4.32, 4.06, 0.073}, {4.36, 4.33, 0.075}, {4.81, 3.65, 0.086}, {2.81, 3.51, 0.088}, {3.79, 3.87, 0.088}}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All], ContourLabels -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may require some fine tuning, but you can get the idea:

```
data = {{21.87, 6.76, 0.045}, {13.86, 4.79, 0.053}, {13.22, 3.8, 0.063}, 
        {11.41, 4.62, 0.064}, {4.32, 4.06, 0.073}, {4.36, 4.33, 0.075}, 
        {4.81, 3.65, 0.086}, {2.81, 3.51, 0.088}, {3.79, 3.87, 0.088}}; 
ListContourPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All]] /. 
               Tooltip[{_, Line[l_]}, val_] :> Text[val, l[[IntegerPart[Length@l/2]]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your help! these labels don't specify their exact positions on the contour, do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Also, how come all the contour lines disappeared except one line where no label was shown! Sorry I am not familiar with using ToolTip